# Java binary (.class) file format parser?

Tags: java, .class-file

I am looking for a tool (or chain of tools) that can parse a .class files to a Java object. Something like :

```
JavaClass parsed = myTool.parse("/some_folder/SomeClassFile.class");
```

The parsed object would have methods like :

```
List<JavaMethod> methods = parsed.getMethods();
List<JavaInterface> interfaces = parsed.getImplementedInterfaces();
List<JavaMethod> calls = someMethod.getCalls();
```

My constraints are :

1. The aim is to parse all classes of a project, including jars, so performance **does** matter.
2. The parser has to parse Java 8 .class files
3. Java is my main language so it's better for me if it's in Java.

Of course I can do some coding, so for example if the output is xml it's ok.

So here are the options I have found so far - none being satisfying as it is :

1. **BCEL or ASM** look like a weapon of choice, but they also look like they're not maintained anymore. Besides, they're a little overkill for my purpose.
2. **Elipse AST** would work, but from what I saw it's only for source files, and I need to parse binary files (jars...)
3. **A grammar for a parsing engine like antlr, yacc, bison**... would work, but I have yet to find a reference grammar for .class files ! Besides, antlr is for text files, and I don't know of another reference Java parser engine (as I said, I would like a Java tool better).
4. I first thought a **class loader** would do the job, and that I could just load the class and then use reflection. But actually I realized I need stuff that the Java reflection api doesn't provide, like getting calls from a particular method.

So here is where I am now ! Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Have you considered using a decompiler to get source, and then parsing that?

Comment: ASM is very fast and is still being maintained (best choice IMO).

Comment: ASM is used inside OpenJDK.  It's still maintained.

Comment: I love grammars, but here I would rather implement the parsing myself. Unsigned shorts, alignment, table indexes, indirections, are more suited to data structures one can short-cut and validate.

Comment: Not sure why you are rejecting (4).  The reflection API gives you the information you want.  With a custom classloader, you can basically get what you want w/o dependencies on external libraries.

Comment: @soong I wouldn't do that for performance reasons. I think .class are designed to be easy to parse, and .java files are not... not to mention you have to parse twice

Comment: @ewh Actually I realized I need some stuff (like what methods a method references to) that reflection api won't give me. I'm editing my question to take that into account.

Comment: @yannick1976 Years ago, I used the ASM library to do something like you are asking for.  It would dump information in XML format.  For each method of a class, I included any methods it would call.

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at the findbugs source code. Since it is able to do method resolution (which is a really complicated business) and is based on class files, it must contain some code that does what you need. It's open source, so if you dig enough you'll probably find everything there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend ASM. From what I've seen, it's by far the most popular Java bytecode library, and yes, it is still maintained. At time of writing, it looks like [the most recent change](http://websvn.ow2.org/log.php?repname=asm&path=%2Ftrunk%2F&isdir=1&) was 41 days ago. So it's not constantly churning but it's not like it's abandoned either. And with such a commonly used library, support should be easy to find.

Comment: Ok I'll go for ASM then ! Thanks everyone

Comment: Just following up : I used ASM and it is awesome.

Comment: @Antimony: can it directly access .class files from the jar or the jar needs to be extracted first?

Answer (score 0):

I made some test for JBBP to parse java class, take a look at it, may be it will be useful for you https://github.com/raydac/java-binary-block-parser/blob/master/src/test/java/com/igormaznitsa/jbbp/it/ClassParsingTest.java